# Python pandas delimiter misprint - double sign

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

This is my code to open file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_df, delimiter='|')
```

I get error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 13571, saw 6

When I check this particular line, I see that there was a misprint and there were 3 signs "|||" instead of one. I would prefer treat double and triple signs as one. Probably, there is other solution.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: is it a misprint where the delimiter is tripled, or is it a malformed file where the `|` was the value of that field and it hasn't been escaped when it was written?

Comment: Question referred to the general case where by some reason the delimiter sign was doubled. Can't see the difference here between misprint and malformed file. Would the solutions be different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use regex separator `[|]+` - one or more `|`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""a|b|c
ss|||s|s
t|g|e"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="[|]+",engine='python')

print (df)
    a  b  c
0  ss  s  s
1   t  g  e
```

Comment: not seeing the data is awkward, but if he was expecting 5 fields and `|||` meant he saw 6, doesn't that mean that this is caused by a field that should contain a `|` character? That would mean that treating the `|||` as one delimiter will misalign the columns in the other direction.

Comment: if you have a line `1|2|3|4|5` you have 5 columns, if you have 1|2|3|||5` you have 6 columns with `sep='|'` and 4 columns with `sep='[|]+'`

Comment: @Stael - yes, I understand. pandas try count columns from header, I think `sep='|'` working nice if data are changed from `ss|||s|s` to `ss||s`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. I was wrong, in this particular question the problem was different. There was one | sign in the text like: "This is a | sample".

Answer (score 3):

**Another way to define a delimiter is using `sep` while reading a CSV in pandas.**

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_df, sep=r'\|+', engine='python')
```

Whenever you notice 'C error', it requires the forced use of python engine by specifying `engine='python'` in the arguments.

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks for the edit. I didn't notice the ||| in the question.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise `sep` and `delimiter` do the same thing. Don't get caught off guard, please read the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

my suspicion is that this would be caused by the file being written incorrectly, if the field was supposed to contain the value "|" but somehow was written incorrectly (csv would normally write a line like that as `1|2|3|"|"|5`), but if it was mistakenly written without any escaping it would cause this issue.

In that case I don't think you can solve this with pandas, because the issue is badly formed csv.

If it's a one off you can just edit the file first, perhaps to replace all "|||" with "||" - but again that could have unintended consequences. I've had this trouble before and I don't think there's a better way than manually editing the file (at least pandas gives you the line number to look at!)

On the other hand, if it really is just a repeated character misprint, then the other answer will work fine.